# Parent Theme Style Loading After Bootstrap Style

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a child theme to my parent theme and am running into an issue.  I am using the child theme functions.php file to call the parent theme .css.  The issue with this is that the parent style.css is being called before the bootstrap.css only on my child theme.  I have tried using the $dependencies argument but it still isn't working.  Was looking for an easy correct solution.

```
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-style', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style('alphamedia-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), 'bootstrap-style');
```

That is the code I am using in my parent functions.php file but it still isn't working.

I'm sure it is something simple I am overlooking.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is the problem with the parent theme or the child theme? Does your child theme enqueue styles - if so please show it and also please show the entire function and the add action.

Answer (score 0):

Your on the right track with this but the `wp_enqueue_style();` function expects an array to be passed as the $dependencies. Try this:

```
wp_enqueue_style('alphamedia-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('bootstrap-style'));
```